# Look for complement of unicode range in python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a set of words and I want to find those who contain non italian characters. Instead of providing all the possible unicode ranges of letters not belonging to the italian alphabet, I think it would be much better to specify the ranges of the allowed letters and then check if a string contains any character not belonging to those ranges. The problem is, I don't know how to tell Python's `re` module to look for these chars, and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Here's an example: the range for lowercase latin letters is `u0061 - u007a`, so if I run the following:

`print(re.search("[\u0061-\u007a]", 'hello'))`

I get as output: `<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='h'>`, as expected.

Now let's add an out of range character to the input string, and make it `Àhello`. I want to search for the character outside the provided range. I tried adding the '^' character before the range:

```
print(re.search("^[\u0061-\u007a]", 'Àhello'))
```

but I get `None` as output. I would like to avoid having to scan each string by character. Is it possible?

Comment: The `^` to negate a character set goes *inside* the square brackets (it must be the first character).  A caret outside of a character set has the entirely unrelated meaning of anchoring the match to the start of the string.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `^` symbol inside the square brackets:

```
print(re.search("[^\u0061-\u007a]", 'Àhello'))
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct answer. To give it a little more context for the OP to understand the issue:
The `^` inside the brackets negates the group. This is what you wanted to achieve. The `^` outside the brackets at the beginning of the regex defines that the match must be a the beginning of the string in order to match.

You can check the RegExr examples here to see difference and in the toolbox at the bottom you get a detailed explanation of the regex.
Beginning of line: https://regexr.com/6dsen
  Negated set: https://regexr.com/6dseq

Comment: Oh, yes, this used to be a common mistake by me. @lwohlhart